# How to test a REST API that call a FeignClient?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, jhipster, junit5, spring-cloud-feign

I am using Jhipster to do 2 microservices. One microservice calls the other microservice using FeignClient, but when I try to test the first microservice it gives an error, I think the cause is the feignClient. In these cases, what is recommended to do?
Any recommendation is appreciated

ReservationResource

```
@PostMapping("/reservations")
public ResponseEntity<?> createReservation(@RequestBody Reservation reservation){

    Reservation result = reservationService.saveReservation(reservation);

    return ResponseEntity
        .created(new URI("/api/reservations/" + result.getId()))
        .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
        .body(result);
}
```

ReservationServiceImpl

This class call feignClient before save the reservation.

```
@Override
public Reservation saveReservation(Reservation reservation) {
    roomFeignClient.updateRoomByNumber(reservation.getRoom());

    return save(reservation);
}
```

ReservationResourceIT

Test class auto generated by Jhipster

```
@IntegrationTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WithMockUser
class ReservationResourceIT {

    private static final Long DEFAULT_CLIENT = 1L;
    private static final Long UPDATED_CLIENT = 2L;

    private static final Long DEFAULT_ROOM = 101L;
    private static final Long UPDATED_ROOM = 2L;

    private static final LocalDate DEFAULT_ENTRY_DATE = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(0L);
    private static final LocalDate UPDATED_ENTRY_DATE = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    private static final LocalDate DEFAULT_OUT_DATE = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(0L);
    private static final LocalDate UPDATED_OUT_DATE = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    private static final Double DEFAULT_TOTAL_PRICE = 1D;
    private static final Double UPDATED_TOTAL_PRICE = 2D;

    private static final String ENTITY_API_URL = "/api/reservations";
    private static final String ENTITY_API_URL_ID = ENTITY_API_URL + "/{id}";

    private static Random random = new Random();
    private static AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong(random.nextInt() + (2 * Integer.MAX_VALUE));

    @Autowired
    private ReservationRepository reservationRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc restReservationMockMvc;

    private Reservation reservation;

    public static Reservation createEntity(EntityManager em) {
        Reservation reservation = new Reservation()
            .client(DEFAULT_CLIENT)
            .room(DEFAULT_ROOM)
            .entryDate(DEFAULT_ENTRY_DATE)
            .outDate(DEFAULT_OUT_DATE)
            .totalPrice(DEFAULT_TOTAL_PRICE);
        return reservation;
    }

    public static Reservation createUpdatedEntity(EntityManager em) {
        Reservation reservation = new Reservation()
            .client(UPDATED_CLIENT)
            .room(UPDATED_ROOM)
            .entryDate(UPDATED_ENTRY_DATE)
            .outDate(UPDATED_OUT_DATE)
            .totalPrice(UPDATED_TOTAL_PRICE);
        return reservation;
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void initTest() {
        reservation = createEntity(em);
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
    @Transactional
    void createReservation() throws Exception {
        int databaseSizeBeforeCreate = reservationRepository.findAll().size();
        // Create the Reservation
        restReservationMockMvc
            .perform(post(ENTITY_API_URL).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(reservation)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());

        // Validate the Reservation in the database
        List<Reservation> reservationList = reservationRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(reservationList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeCreate + 1);
        Reservation testReservation = reservationList.get(reservationList.size() - 1);
        assertThat(testReservation.getClient()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_CLIENT);
        assertThat(testReservation.getRoom()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_ROOM);
        assertThat(testReservation.getEntryDate()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_ENTRY_DATE);
        assertThat(testReservation.getOutDate()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_OUT_DATE);
        assertThat(testReservation.getTotalPrice()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_TOTAL_PRICE);
    }
}
```

Here is the error message when I run the test

```
2021-12-10 14:08:25.302 DEBUG 16236 --- [           main] reactor.util.Loggers                     : Using Slf4j logging framework
2021-12-10 14:08:25.304 DEBUG 16236 --- [           main] reactor.core.publisher.Hooks             : Hooking onLastOperator: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext
2021-12-10 14:08:25.689 DEBUG 16236 --- [           main] feign.template.Template                  : Explicit slash decoding specified, decoding all slashes in uri
2021-12-10 14:08:25.857  WARN 16236 --- [oundedElastic-1] o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for service: roomservice
2021-12-10 14:08:25.859  WARN 16236 --- [           main] .s.c.o.l.FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient : Service instance was not resolved, executing the original request
2021-12-10 14:08:32.730  WARN 16236 --- [oundedElastic-1] o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for service: roomservice
2021-12-10 14:08:32.731  WARN 16236 --- [           main] .s.c.o.l.FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient : Service instance was not resolved, executing the original request
2021-12-10 14:08:32.771 ERROR 16236 --- [           main] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Internal Server Error

feign.RetryableException: roomservice executing GET http://roomservice/api/rooms/state/101
    at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:249)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:129)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy195.changeStateRoom(Unknown Source)
    at com.hotel.reservation.service.impl.ReservationServiceImpl.changeStateRoom(ReservationServiceImpl.java:149)
    at com.hotel.reservation.service.impl.ReservationServiceImpl.saveReservation(ReservationServiceImpl.java:165)
    at com.hotel.reservation.service.impl.ReservationServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9845a4f5.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at com.hotel.reservation.service.impl.ReservationServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bb12020f.saveReservation(<generated>)
    at com.hotel.reservation.web.rest.ReservationResource.createReservation(ReservationResource.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:584)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at com.hotel.reservation.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:37)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:183)
    at com.hotel.reservation.web.rest.ReservationResourceIT.createReservation(ReservationResourceIT.java:110)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: roomservice
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:229)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1253)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
    at feign.Client$Default.convertResponse(Client.java:108)
    at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:104)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerUtils.executeWithLoadBalancerLifecycleProcessing(LoadBalancerUtils.java:56)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.RetryableFeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.lambda$execute$2(RetryableFeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:156)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.RetryableFeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.execute(RetryableFeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:103)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:119)
    ... 156 common frames omitted


MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/reservations
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"84"]
             Body = {"client":1,"room":101,"entryDate":[1970,1,1],"outDate":[1970,1,1],"totalPrice":1.0}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.hotel.reservation.web.rest.ReservationResource
           Method = com.hotel.reservation.web.rest.ReservationResource#createReservation(Reservation)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = feign.RetryableException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 500
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Content-Type:"application/problem+json", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY", Content-Security-Policy:"default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:", Referrer-Policy:"strict-origin-when-cross-origin", Feature-Policy:"geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'"]
     Content type = application/problem+json
             Body = {"type":"https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message","title":"Internal Server Error","status":500,"detail":"roomservice executing GET http://roomservice/api/rooms/state/101","path":"/api/reservations","message":"error.http.500"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
2021-12-10 14:08:32.854 DEBUG 16236 --- [           main] reactor.core.publisher.Hooks             : Reset onLastOperator: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<201> but was:<500>
Expected :201
Actual   :500
<Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
```

Comment: As the error shows, the feign client tries to connect to a host named like your microservice `roomservice` because normally this is converted to an ip address or real hostname using information from service registry. Which registry are you using?

Comment: I am using Jhipster Registry that is a Eureka server

Comment: Well the question is what kind of test do you want to write? Unit tests: you should mock the feign client or any service that requires an external dependency. Integration tests: then you should run the 2 microservices and eureka server.

Comment: I want to write integration tests. My 2 microservices and the eureka server are running when I run the test, but the error still keeps getting

Comment: So it means your test is not fetching the registry from your eureka server, probably a misconfiguration. Why do you want to write integration tests , you're not going to be able to test corner cases and setup is much more complex.  `@IntegrationTest` are not integrations tests in the sense you use it with your 2 microservices and the eureka server running.